# How do I access the array submit() calls in the dom?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to grab all the inputs inside a form, in order to submit them.
The point of this is to use jquery's ajax to submit a dynamically sized form.
Surely there must be an array inside the dom somewhere which i can just do something like...
    docment.forms['form'].elements
which only lists inputs for that form, meaning I can loop through them and grab their values to play around with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector for this.

```
$('#formid:input')
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to serialize all inputs into a ready-to-use query string for the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)'s `data` parameter.

```
$('#formid').submit(function() {
    alert($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document.forms['form'].elements)
```